# printing files using php

Tags: php, printing

I have a question about printing files using php scripting .

is there any linux printing library to be installed on the server ?
i've tried the lpr command with exec , shell_exec , and system functions .
but non of theme worked with me .

example 1:

```
$filedir = "/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/print/file/test.txt"  ;
echo shell_exec("lpr $filedir");
```

example 2:

```
$filedir = "/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/print/file/test.txt"  ;
echo shell_exec("lpr -P printername $filedir");
```

example 3:

```
$filedir = "/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/print/file/test.txt"  ;
echo exec("lpr $filedir");
```

example 4:

```
$filedir = "/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/print/file/test.txt"  ;
echo shell_exec("lpr -P printername $filedir");
```

example 5:

```
$filedir = "/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/print/file/test.txt"  ;
echo system("lp $filedir");
```

also iv'e tried this class 
 [here](http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/php-print/)  but it shows me a warning msg and print nothing

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to tcp://1.1.1.1:515 (Connection timed out) in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/print/PrintSendLPR.php on line 122

also i have checked a lot of examples as  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694144/printing-over-network-from-php-app)  ,  [here](http://phpdave.wordpress.com/tag/lpr/)  , and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377135/how-to-convert-documents-to-pdf-on-a-linux-php-stack)

any help please ! 
i have to print out a file with php code which is hosted on a Linux server , i need to connect to the user's default printer or to install a printer-library/driver into the server .

Many thanks

Comment: Are you creating a command line script or a web application. I.e. will your user's access your script through a terminal or through a browser?

Comment: In that case I'm guessing you'll need to install a printer on the server, as any exec command in PHP will only have access to whatever is installed on the server. Here's a link to some more info about CLI printing in Linux http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-Usage-HOWTO-2.html. Unfortunately I can't help with suggesting any drivers to install.

Comment: okay thanks , i'll check the links you've posted
- many thanks :)